# Importing SPSS file in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read SPSS file in R with read.spss function of foreign Package.
There are two instances of importing which i will reflect here. At first instance when i import the datafile of 1 month, with the command `read.spss(spssfile,to.data.frame = T)`, it imports the attribute as a factor variable with levels attached to it. For instance, below is output of the variable levels of the variable just as how the factor variable looks in R.

```
52 Levels: Barrilito Bohemia Bud Light Budweiser Carta Blanca Coors Coors Light Corona ... Bocanegra
```

[Screenshot of the output of the variable in console is in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRbEk.png)

Now when i import the same data of 27 months using the same command `spss.get(spssfile,use.value.labels = T)`, it imports the same attribute with levels and labels attached to it for that particular attribute.

[Output in console of the same attribute from 27 months datafile is given in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtOIg.png)

My requirement is consistency in importing the data file in the format like given in the first screenshot i attached i.e. all attribute should be imported as factor variables and not like levels and labels separately like mentioned in the second screenshot.

Please ask for more clarifications needed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: "when i import the same data of 27 months using the same command"
You are not using the same command.
You first use `read.spss(spssfile,to.data.frame = T)` and then `spss.get(spssfile,use.value.labels = T)`. Different results for different commands are expected.

Comment: My bad.. Its a typo, its actually read.spss and not spss.get. Thanks for correcting